# Android In app billing purchase history query

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I am building an app that I want to use Google in app billing for. Does Google track in-app purchase history for me, so that I can query history and get data, say, by date or by item, etc. Or must my app itself store user's purchase history on my own backend? Also, if you can please provide a link so I can verify this info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your question answer is  both **YES and NO** Google will take care of all purchases based on **product type**. If you are using **Non-consumable or Subscription** based products Google will keep records, in other case if you are using **Consumable** products Google will keep it's record till your app consumes that product.

If your app sends a purchase request Google will associate it with **primary gmail** account registered on android device and will not allow to purchase same product twice.

**NOTE**:- If You are using **IAB-2** then above product type and flow will slightly different
**Non-consumable ** is known as **Managed Products**
**Subscription** is same as **Subscription**
**Consumable** is known as **Unmanaged** products

In case of **IAB-2** google will never keep record of Unmanaged products and it is your responsibility to keep records if you want.

For more details see below link to developer guide.

[Developer guide](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. +1. I am using version 3, and my concern is primarily consumable goods. I have been through the link you point to before posting. I don't remember anything there about historical data that google saves.

Comment: Until you notify to google play app about consumption of product it will behave same as non-consumable product hence user can not purchase same product twice and as soon as you sends notification google again make the product available for purchase. So if you have your own server(which is recommended for implementing secured in-app transaction) you can store this purchase information there and can use in future.

Comment: do i need to verify signature if i am using Non-consumable product?

Comment: I am not sure for now as this API have got changed a lot from the last time I have used. Better to search for that or create a new question